# Is $n! + 1$ often a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Related to [another question (If $n = 51! +1$, then find number of primes among $n+1,n+2,\ldots, n+50$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852598/if-n-51-1-then-find-no-of-primes-among-n1-n2-n50), I wonder: How often is $n!+1$ a prime?

There is a related OEIS sequence [A002981](http://oeis.org/A002981), however, nothing is said if the sequence is finite or not. Does anybody know more about it?

Comment: The $€100$ question - is it true that $n!+1$ is prime for infinitely many $n$'s.

Comment: You would expect there to be an infinite number of them, because if  numbers of the form n!+1 were random w.r.t. primality, then the probability of sucha number being prime would be approximately 1/log(n! + 1) which is approximately 1/[n( log(n)-1)], the summation over n to infinity diverges. But these numbers are not exactly random and they are actually more likely to be prime.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20001/how-many-consecutive-composite-integers-follow-k1

Comment: Also related is the probability that the primorial plus one is a prime

Answer (score 42, accepted):

$n! + 1$ is prime for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 27, 37, 41, 73, 77, 116, 154, 320, 340, 399, 427, 872, 1477, 6380, 26951, 110059, 150209, \dots$, no other factorial primes are known as of May 2014. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime) for more info on *factorial primes*.

Comment: I'm curious, how did they determine that 150209!+1 is prime?  I'd be very interested to know how they determined the primality of 150,000 different million-digit numbers...

Comment: Proving that a number p is a prime is easier if you know the complete factorisation of p+1 or p-1. And of course the factorisation of p-1 is known when p = n! + 1. Proving that a general number of that size is prime would be an awful lot more difficult.

Comment: Looking at http://primes.utm.edu/primes/page.php?id=102627 it looks like that what's Rene Dohmen did, using OpenPFGW.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman In general (ie excluding cases where an easy option is available), proving a number isn't prime is mostly done using algorithms that have a certain probability of finding a factor if one exists.  If those algorithms fail to find a factor after enough iterations that the odds of one existing are very low, a very computationally intensive (on the order of a day of computer time to complete, but better than the naive brute force approach) algorithm is used to do the final proof.  http://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove4.html

Comment: I concur with all the remarks above - there is a slew of algorithms that could help here. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integer_factorization_algorithms. The challenge is to find algorithnms that are polynomial in run time.  For general purpose factoring, the so-called Elliptic Curve Method (invented by my thesis advisor Hendrik Lenstra) is the third-fastest known factoring method. The second fastest is the multiple polynomial quadratic sieve and the fastest is the general number field sieve.

Comment: @NickyHekster:  Are you sure you agree with all the remarks above?  Those are about primality tests, not factorization algorithms.  There are deterministic polynomial time primality tests:  AKS is one.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test  There are no deterministic polynomial time (general) factorization algorithms, although you list the various currently fastest factorization methods in your comment...

Comment: I meant both factorization and primality testing, you are right! I find the discussion valuable.

Comment: In order of difficulty: 1. Find a small factor - well, 150209! + 1 has none :-( 2. Prove that a number is composite by showing that it fails a test for probable primes (for example if a^(p-1) modulo p ≠ 1 for a = 2, 3, 5, 7...) 3. Give evidence that a number is highly probable prime. 4. Proof that a number is prime. 5. Find the factorisation of a number with at least two huge prime factors.

Comment: @DanNeely: No, factoring a number is much much more difficult than proving it has a factor. For example, the 240 digit number RSA-240 has not been factored, and 159209! + 1 is a number of a few hundred thousand digits. Proving that a 240 digit number is composite is quite easy.

Answer (score 19):

Just looking at the heuristics of the problem:

If you pick a random integer $x$, it will be a prime number with a probability about $1 / \ln x$. Now the number $n! + 1$ is not a random integer. We know that $n! + 1$ is not divisible by any prime number $p ≤ n$. A random large integer is not divisible by any prime $p ≤ n$ with probability $(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/5)...$ which is about $1 / (2 \ln n)$. So the likelihood that $n! + 1$ is a prime is accordingly higher, about $2 \ln n / \ln (n!)$.

Using the Stirling formula, $\ln (n!)$ is about $n \ln n - n$ or $n(\ln n - 1)$. So $n!+1$ is prime with probability about $(2/n)/(1 - 1 / \ln n)$.

The factor $(1 - 1 / \ln n)$ is quite close to 1; the number of primes of the form $n! + 1$ with $n ≤ M$ is about $2 \ln M$. Very roughly agrees with the list of primes given earlier (I think it is a list of *known* primes, with many numbers in between not examined).

Answer (score 10):

Such numbers are called *factorial primes*. There is only a limited number of known such numbers.

The largest factorial primes were discovered only recently. From an [announcement of an organization called PrimeGrid PRPNet](http://www.primegrid.com/download/FPS-147855.pdf):

> On 30 August 2013, PrimeGrid’s PRPNet found the 2nd largest known
> Factorial prime: $$147855!-1$$ The prime is $700,177$ digits long. The
> discovery was made by Pietari Snow (Lumiukko) of Finland using an
> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 940 @ 2.93GHz with 6 GB RAM running Linux.
> This computer took just a little over 69 hours and 37 minutes to
> complete the primality test.

[PrimeGrid](http://www.primegrid.com/) is a set of projects based on distributed computing, and devoted to finding primes satisfying various conditions.

Factorial primes-related recent events in PrimeGrid:

$147855!-1$ found: [official announcement](http://www.primegrid.com/download/FPS-147855.pdf)

$110059!+1$ found: [official announcement](http://www.primegrid.com/download/fps-110059.pdf)

$103040!-1$ found: [official announcement](http://www.primegrid.com/download/fps-103040.pdf)

$94550!-1$ found: [official announcement](http://www.primegrid.com/download/fps-94550.pdf)

Other current PrimeGrid activities:

- 321 Prime Search: searching for mega primes of the form $3·2^n±1$.
- Cullen-Woodall Search: searching for mega primes of forms $n·2^n+1$ and $n·2^n−1$.
- Extended Sierpinski Problem: helping solve the Extended Sierpinski Problem.
- Generalized Fermat Prime Search: searching for megaprimes of the form $b2^n+1$.
- Prime Sierpinski Project: helping solve the Prime Sierpinski Problem.
- Proth Prime Search: searching for primes of the form $k·2^n+1$.
- Seventeen or Bust: helping to solve the Sierpinski Problem.
- Sierpinski/Riesel Base 5: helping to solve the Sierpinski/Riesel Base 5 Problem.
- Sophie Germain Prime Search: searching for primes $p$ and $2p+1$.
- The Riesel problem: helping to solve the Riesel Problem.