# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n!+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For some numbers $n!+1$ is prime, but all such numbers are not prime. For example, $5!+1 = 11\times 11$. The question is this:

Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n!+1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time it is unknown.  These are called (together with cases $n!-1$) [factorial primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime).

Chris Caldwell maintains a [page of Factorial Prime Records](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=30), with links to much else.

Caldwell and Yves Gallot have a heuristic argument that there should be infinitely many factorial primes of each form (see their [preprint here](http://www.utm.edu/staff/caldwell/preprints/primorials.pdf)), with the estimate that the chance of $n! \pm 1$ of either form being prime is:

$$ \frac{e^\gamma \log n}{n(\log n - 1)} $$

Integrating this leads to their conjecture that "The expected number of factorial primes of each of the forms $n! \pm 1$ with $n \le N$ are both asymptotic to $e^\gamma \log N$."

Clearly this tends to infinity as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Please see answers to [another related question here (Is n!+1 often a prime?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853085/is-n-1-often-a-prime/853804#853804).

There you can learn:

- what factorial primes are, and how many are known to us at the present moment
- some probability heuristics about existence and frequency of factorial primes
- some collaborative computation efforts to find more factorial primes

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 2):

This is still an open problem, which is to determine whether there exists infinitely many factorial primes (primes of the form $n!\pm1$), according to this [page](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=FactorialPrime).