# Show that $101!+1$ is not prime number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Show that $101!+1$ is not prime number.

How many ways exist to do it?

Comment: what is your appraoch?

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/examples-of-finding-remainders-using-wilson-s-theorem

Comment: @Sara On the other hand, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853085/is-n-1-often-a-prime). There $n=101$ is not in the list, too.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $137\mid 101!+1$.

Comment: It would be interesting to see where you got this factor $137$.

Comment: But how did you come across $137$? Is there a proof or logic for it or do we have to go for such numbers

Comment: It cannot be divisible by any prime $\leq 101$ so reasonable to start trying with the ones just above it.

Comment: To find 137 through the "try the primes just above 101" process, though, we'd need to compute 101! modulo 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, and 137, taking 700 multiplication-modulo-foo operations.  It seems a bit much.  [And a priori there's no guarantee that you'd even find a divisor this way, e.g., if the question was for 103!+1, the smallest prime divisor is 27437.]

Comment: Always an option http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+101!%2B1

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, I think it's somewhat quicker to check if $p$ divides $(p-102)!+1$ for $p=103, 107$, etc.